# creating azure webapp for php web application

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I uploaded folder Called Chat contains `index.php` for chat application to azure from the cloud power shell. now if I change the directory to Chat and run the command (`az webapp up --runtime "PHP|7.3"`) I get the following error:
Could not auto-detect the runtime stack of your app.
HINT: Are you in the right folder?
For more information, see 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109470'
how can I deploy this `php` app from the cloud shell??

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link referenced in the error message, the current support for `az webapp up` includes apps targeting:

- [Python](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/AzWebAppUP/runtime_detection.md#python-detection-logic)
- [Node](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/AzWebAppUP/runtime_detection.md#node-detection-logic)
- [ASP .NET and - .NET Core](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/AzWebAppUP/runtime_detection.md#ASP-.NET-and-.NET-Core-detection-logic)

As part of the execution of `az webapp up` command it performs a **best effort** detection to match your code (in your local directory) with a supported runtime in your Web App. If you want to set the runtime manually you can use the [az webapp create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_create) command.

For a detailed walkthrough on how to deploy a PHP app to Azure App Service, please follow [this quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-php?pivots=platform-windows) depending on your desired hosting platform (Windows/Linux).